# What is the point of the props argument in the setState async setting function

Tags: reactjs

In React when you want to update state based on a previous value of the state, due to some asynchronous qualities about the `setState` method, you need to pass in a function as the first param so that at the time state is actually being updated `setState` has access to the most up to date version of the state. e.g.

```
const setStateCallback = prevState => {
  return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + this.props.step};
}

this.setState(setStateCallback);
```

My question is what is the point of the `props` argument in this function if state is the only piece of data is potentially out of date. Why not just use

```
const setStateCallback =  prevState => {
  return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + this.props.step};
}

this.setState(setStateCallback);
```

The way I assume `setState` is working is that `setStateCallback` gets stored and will be invoked once `React` is ready to process all of the `setState` calls.  At that time, yes I would need to have access to the state updates that have happened during with other `setState` calls in the process. However, when `setStateCallback` is called any updates that were made to `this.props.step` in the meantime would still be available on `this.props.step` because I am referencing the `this.props` object. If I did this

```
const step = this.props.step

const setStateCallback =  prevState => {
  return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + step};
}

this.setState(setStateCallback);
```

This is a problem because the value of `step` (assuming this is a Number or String) is no longer being referenced off the props object and could be out of date.

So given my assumptions are correct, accessing the `props` argument given to the callback `setStateCallback` seems unnecessary.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by Brad Bumbalough, and a little extra evidence by myself below, the `props` arg is indeed necessary.

The implications of this finding mean you must be careful whenever accessing `this.state` or `this.props` within your custom class methods.  For example, for any custom class methods called within a `setState` callback you need to make sure that any references within those methods or references within subsequent class methods made from that call take `state` and `props` as arguments and don't refer to the `this.props` or `this.state`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think their point is that everything is asynchronous. So, if you are expressly depending on `props` for your state change, you can't be 100% certain that `this.props` hasn't changed after the `setState` call is first queued.

**A possible lifecycle of when this would be a problem could be...**

1. Initial render.
2. Async call to get data from server.
3. User interaction triggers a `setState` call that depends on current props (`prevState.myInteger + props.step`). This will be evaluated *immediately* with current state/props, and the result gets stored as the new value for the state attribute.
4. `setState` call is queued.
5. Async call returns and updates parent component/store, trigging props to change.
6. `setState` call is processed and applied, but the props used to generate the stored state data is now out of sync with the current props the user can see, leading to confusion, chaos, and WW3. Ok, I might have exaggerated there.

The key is that it ***might*** change. 99% of the time you probably won't need to drill this specific into the call. But the call is there, if you so need it.

In case anyone else was looking, here's the [link to the docs on this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.
>
> To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your assumption on 3.

Comment: I just updated the question to clearer illustrate my assumptions.  What do you think?

Comment: Thanks! I check it a little later this evening and update accordingly.

Comment: OK I spent some time reading this article http://reactkungfu.com/2016/03/dive-into-react-codebase-handling-state-changes/ and it looks like the answer is in `updateComponent` implemenation.   It appears the reference to `this.props` can possibly be switched _after_ all of the `setState` callbacks are called.  That means references to `this.props` within a `setState` callback are not guaranteed to be up to date and and the `props` argument is your only guarantee that you have the most up to date props.